# Javascript style media query

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the best way to replicate a CSS media query in Javascript?

I have a script that I only want to run on wider viewport widths, which I've achieved (see example code). However I'd like to check on resize as well.

I know most normally people won't resize their browser window so onload is fine but I'm concerned that if someone switches between portrait and landscape views on the tablet the script could cause issues.

As this script affects how the navigation functions on mobile/tablet devices I think it could be important hear to check on resize?

```
if ( $(window).width() > 1024) { /* [1] */   

    $(function() {
        var $el,
            leftPos,
            newWidth,
            $mainNav = $(".site-nav__list");

        $mainNav.append("<div class='site-nav__line'></div>");
        var $magicLine = $(".site-nav__line"),
            $currentMenu = $(".current-menu-item");

        $magicLine
            .width($currentMenu.length ? $currentMenu.width() : 0)
            .css("left", $currentMenu.length ? $currentMenu.find("a").position().left : 0)
            .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
            .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

        var hoverOut;

        $(".site-nav__list li a").hover(function() {
            clearTimeout(hoverOut);

                $el = $(this);
                leftPos = $el.position().left;
                newWidth = $el.parent().width();

                if (!$magicLine.width()) {
                    $magicLine.stop().hide().css({
                        left: leftPos,
                        width: newWidth
                    }).fadeIn(100);
                } else {
                    $magicLine.stop().animate({
                        opacity: 1,
                        left: leftPos,
                        width: newWidth
                    });
                }
            },
            function() {
                hoverOut = setTimeout(function() {
                    if (!$currentMenu.length) {
                        $magicLine.fadeOut(100, function() {
                            $magicLine.css({
                                left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
                                width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
                            });
                        });
                    } else {
                        $magicLine.stop().animate({
                            left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
                            width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
                        });
                    }
                }, 100);
            }
        );
    });

}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking exactly. If you want to adjust things on resize, use `$(window).on('resize'), function() { ... })`.

Comment: Hey, yeah so basically the script 'works'. But I want it to check again after resize and run/disable the script if required if the width is greater/less than 1024px.

Comment: OK. Well you can't "disable" the script like that, you'd have to undo what the script did previously. Basically you need a function that is called on page load and on resize, that adjusts things depending on whether page width is above the threshold or not.

Comment: Yeah I used 'disable' for want of a better word. So basically it runs above 1024px but not if below that width. It currently does that (on page load), I just need it to check again if the viewports width changes. Any ideas? I tried that example code but it throw up some errors. Thanks again!

Comment: Did you read my first comment? I don't see that event being handled in your sample. You might want to edit your post if you did.

Comment: Yeah, if I wrapped that around my code it broke unfortunately. In my code `if ( $(window).width() > 1024) {` is checking if the browser window is greater/less than 1024px but that's just on load. So it's the resize bit I need to hook up with the condition that the browser window is greater than 1024px in width.

Comment: If I wrap my code in ` $( window ).resize(function() { ... });` the code doesn't load, until I resize the browser. And as the script adds a div into the main navigation it basically adds a new div every time you resize :/

Comment: Reread my second comment (third one including yours), carefully, I already mentioned that ("**on page load and on resize**"). Can't make the code for you especially without seeing the HTML that goes with it, so you'll have to give it a try first and edit your question. Good luck.